# Using imageCFC how can I create a image object?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I need an alternative to using the CF function imageNew(). I started to use ImageCFC. However I cannot find a way to read an image and create an image object using imageCFC. It only seems to write to file from the API docs found here (http://www.opensourcecf.com/imagecfc/docs/imageCFC.cfm).

My question is using imageCFC how can I create a image object without writing to file?

```
imageCFC = createObject("component","imagecfc.image" );
local.img1 = imageCFC.readImage("D:\#arguments.directory#\#arguments.imageName#");

// turn this into an image object here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that, with ImageCFC, you need to step down to Java in order to create an image. There is an Image.cfc that is part of MangoBlog's asset manager that has a very nice example of a createImage function that utilizes Java's BufferedImage object.

[MangoBlog Image.cfc](http://code.google.com/p/mangoblog/source/browse/trunk/src/coldfusion/application/components/plugins/system/AssetManager/Image.cfc?r=566)